# Numerical equality symbol for variables with different units

Tags: notation, unit-of-measure

Good day! I wonder, is there any **equality symbol** for variables with different units of measurements?

For instance, it is given $Ce = 3$ $[V*s/rad]$ which is back-EMF constant of a motor and $Cm$ - torque constant of a motor in $[N*m/A]$. For DC motor this constants are **numericaly equal**.

How symbolically indicate that they are equal? Because I think it is incorrect to say $Cm = Ce$, as they are variables with different units of measurements.

Comment: I have never seen that, but I also don't see a need.

Comment: Given any two quantities with incompatible dimensions, there are units that they could be measured in that would have the same result. One merely has to define the units in such a way they come out to be the same. E.g., measuring distance in "triple nano-feet" instead of in meters. So it is pointless to consider two quantities with incompatible dimensions as being "numerically equal". It is just a chance coincidence that only holds for a particular set of units. When measured in other units, it is not true. There is only value in such comparisons when the dimensions can be measured the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that exists a *precise* symbol for what you are looking for and sincerely I don't even see a need! You could come up with your notation if you want like stating that the *magnitude* of that two physical measurement are the same but it will be still imprecise if you want to be pedantic about it.

If you want to be creative you can use something like this $$C_m\cong C_e\;\;\;C_m\doteq C_e\;\;\;C_m\simeq C_e$$
You could even go to crazier places with something like that $$C_m\bowtie C_e\;\;\;C_m\triangleright C_e$$
sky is the limit: choose one that you like and define it as "[...] where *this symbol* is being use to indicate that  this constants are numericaly equal [...]"

Answer (score -1):

It's rare, but some antique books used to show numerically equal as an equal with a "N" above.

Comment: It would be nice if you gave an example.